# Random Picture Shorten

Tags: java

I only have a day experience with eclipse and java language, today I have been answered by many people here and successfully developed an application just the way I wanted it to be :). Thank you all for that!

Now what I need is, I have this code here:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final int[] photos={R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};

    final ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

    final Random ran=new Random();
    int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
```

And in this code it uses only img1-img4, but I have 25 images in my folder, but the app only shows these 4. I could add all 25 in the code, and later as I will have over 100 images then I can just add them all in the code, but is there any way to shorten it out? I will always name them img1...img25...img62...img99 and so on, what code should I use for it to recognize and use all the images in the folder and not only the written ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, very easy.

```
  for(int x = 0;x<numberofimages;x++) {
      R.drawable.img + x; //put your code here, the thing I put is wrong.
  }
```

I know that the text inside the for loop is wrong, but you can figure that out I think :)